# When to hide show more button

Tags: ajax, pagination

I am use a load more button in place of pagination. I just using jquery and ajax using this [post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18167/show-more-entries-on-click) as a starting point.

The problem I'm having is how to hide the button when there is no more posts to show. I thought I could do this with pagination but its not working out.

Here is my blog index:

```
            {% paginate craft.entries.section('blog').limit(2) as pageInfo, blogEntries %}

        <div id="post-output">

            {% for entry in blogEntries %}
                <article>
                    <h3><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h3>
                    <p>Posted on {{ entry.postDate.format('F d, Y') }}</p>
                    <p><a href="{{ entry.url }}">Continue reading</a></p>
                </article>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>

        {% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}

            <button id="more-button" data-page="{{craft.request.getPageNum()}}" data-batch="2">Load More</button>

        {% endif %}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$("#more-button").on('click', function () {
var btn = $(this),
    page = btn.data('page'),
    batch = btn.data('batch'),
    offset = page * batch,
    newPage = page + 1;

loadPosts(offset, batch);
// set the buttons page attribute to the new page it is on.
btn.data('page',newPage);

console.log('page');
console.log(newPage);
});

function loadPosts (offset, limit) {
$.get('/ajax/posts', { offset:offset, limit:limit }, function (data) {
    var postOutput = $('#post-output');
    postOutput.append(data);
});
}
```

and here is the ajax/_posts:

```
{% set offset = craft.app.request.getParam('offset') %}
{% set limit = craft.app.request.getParam('limit') %}
{% set moreitems = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(limit).offset(offset).all() %}

{% for entry in moreitems %}
<article>
    <h3><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h3>
    <p>Posted on {{ entry.postDate.format('F d, Y') }}</p>
    <p><a href="{{ entry.url }}">Continue reading</a></p>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't think of clean way to do this without PHP. You could eventually return a hidden input field with the remaining number of elements and check this input value with javascript after you appended the html but I'm not really a friend of avoiding PHP for certain reasons. The other way would be to check the lenght of `data` and hide the container if it's 0

Comment: @RobinSchambach your comment gave me an idea. here is what I did in my blog index: `{% set numOfpages = pageInfo.totalPages %}
   
<button id="more-button" data-page="{{craft.app.request.pageNum()}}" data-batch="2" data-total="{{ numOfpages}}">Load More</button>`

Comment: and in the javascript: `$("#more-button").on('click', function () {
    var btn = $(this),
        page = btn.data('page'),
        batch = btn.data('batch'),
        total = btn.data('total'),
        offset = page * batch,
        newPage = page + 1;
    if ( newPage <= total ) {
        loadPosts(offset, batch);
        btn.data('page',newPage);
    }
    if ( newPage == total ) {
        $('#more-button').hide();
    }
});

Comment: @DanielleFrappier if that solution worked for you, would you mind adding that as an official answer?

Comment: Sure no problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did in my blog index:

```
        {% paginate craft.entries.section('blog').limit(1) as pageInfo, blogEntries %}

        <div id="post-output">

            {% for entry in blogEntries %}
                <article>
                    <h3><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h3>
                    <p>Posted on {{ entry.postDate.format('F d, Y') }}</p>
                    <p><a href="{{ entry.url }}">Continue reading</a></p>
                </article>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>

        {% set numOfpages = pageInfo.totalPages %}

        <button id="more-button" data-page="{{craft.app.request.pageNum()}}" data-batch="1" data-total="{{ numOfpages}}">Load More</button>
```

and in my javascript:

```
$("#more-button").on('click', function () {
var btn = $(this),
    page = btn.data('page'),
    batch = btn.data('batch'),
    total = btn.data('total'),
    offset = page * batch,
    newPage = page + 1;

console.log(newPage);
console.log(total);

if ( newPage <= total ) {

    loadPosts(offset, batch);
    // set the buttons page attribute to the new page it is on.
    btn.data('page',newPage);
}

if ( newPage == total ) {
    $('#more-button').hide();
}

});

function loadPosts (offset, limit) {
$.get('/ajax/posts', { offset:offset, limit:limit }, function (data) {
    var postOutput = $('#post-output');
    postOutput.append(data);
});
}
```